# Unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
title = input ("Enter book title: ")
author = input ("Enter author: ")
num_of_pages = input ("Enter num_of_pages: ")
the_first_main_character = input ("Enter the first main character: ")
the_second_main_character = input ("Enter the second main character: ")
print ("Book description", \n title, \n author, \n num_of_pages, \n the_first_main_character, \n the_second_main_character)
```

пишет `unexpected character after line continuation character` 
Меняла / на , добавляла запятые, кавычки, точки после переменных.

Comment: `print ("Book description", title, author, num_of_pages, the_first_main_character, the_second_main_character, sep="\n")`

Comment: sep="" : Строка, которой следует разделить объекты. None — использовать значение по умолчанию. Ожидается, что аргумент будет передан по имени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
author = input ("Enter author: ")
num_of_pages = input ("Enter num_of_pages: ")
the_first_main_character = input ("Enter the first main character: ")
the_second_main_character = input ("Enter the second main character: ")
print ("Book description\n", title + '\n', author + '\n', num_of_pages + '\n',
        the_first_main_character + '\n', the_second_main_character)
```

Comment: То есть перенос строки \n имеет тип str и обращатся с ним нужно как со строкой.